# Apcahe Camel: How can I a route participate in Hibernate Transaction?

Tags: hibernate, apache-camel

Is it possible for Camel route to participate in a Hibernate Transaction?
In the middle of a hibernate transaction, I want to create a file using Camel's file component. But I want to delete created file, if transaction fails.

Is there any way that camel route be aware of the hibernate transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A route can indeed participate in a transaction with [hibernate](http://camel.apache.org/hibernate-example.html). Note that only [transactional endpoints](http://camel.apache.org/transactional-client.html) can participate in a transaction - and that if you need to cover multiple resources within a transaction you need to use some JTA compliant transaction manager, such as a Java EE server. I.e. a hibernate transaction manager will only handle hibernate beans (endpoints in 2.11) etc.

You can of course define an error handler in your route that, if the file exists, it deletes it. But it will not be "transactional" since there is no concept of rollback/commit. You have no guarantee that the files really gets deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use on completion to trigger custom logic onFailure / onCompletion. And then you can delete the file if the transaction failed.
http://camel.apache.org/oncompletion.html

But the error handler works as well.